# Bazel- How to depend in tests on files with location from "convention" ($Module/src/main/webapp)

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, bazel

Again migrating large Maven codebase to Bazel.
I have tests which try to read some files from the user.dir (like files from `src/main/webapp` mainly for easier test running in IntelliJ).
I'm trying to understand how I can change them to read the files during Bazel build.
Think of the following structure:

- RepoRoot

  - SomeModule

    - src/main

      - webapp (contains WEB-INF/web.xml for example)
      - scala/com/wix/someCode (BUILD file at somCode)
    - BUILD (filegroup exposing src/main/webapp files)

Given I have several `SomeModule`s and they share a test utility which exposes `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml` to them as a `File` (can't be changed to `FileInputStream`) I'm trying to understand how best expose these files to the tests and test-utility.
 If I define in `someCode` the dependency of `src/main/webapp` as:

1. data- the files will be exposed as files in the runfiles **but** will sit in `user.dir/SomeModule/src/main/webapp` and the test utility doesn't know which of the `SomeModule`s it's in.
2. resources- the files will be exposed on the classpath but not as files (`jar` scheme)
3. classpath_resources- the files will be directly on `user.dir` but AFAIU without `src/main/webapp`

The solution I've currently thought about is exposing it as `data` and using `$(location)` expansion to pass the location in the `runfiles` to the tests in a system property. The main problem I have with this method is that I think tests won't work in IntelliJ (unless the Bazel plugin supports both `$(location)` expansion and **automatically** passing the jvm_flags to the tests).

My questions are:

1. What is the best practice for this problem?
2. If it's the `data` and `$(location)` expansion then how to handle IntelliJ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I talked to the maintainer of the Intellij plugin and he thinks that putting it in `data` and finding it by `$(location)` should "just work." (If it doesn't, he requests that you file a bug.)

The plugin should, theoretically, handle any valid Bazel project.

Comment: Thanks! Would you say it's the best practice?

Comment: I think so, given the constraints.